# Bash test value evaluation

Tags: bash, shell

I am learning about shell scripting, particularly the shell commands `test`, `[ ]`. `[[ ]]` and `(( ))`, I wrote a real simple script to test my understanding, it takes in three arguments, if all three are integers (and the second argument is lower than the third) it tests if the first argument lays in the range between the second and third. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#test if arg1 is contained in the range [arg2, arg3]

function isint()
{
    if [[ "$1" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo $1 is integer
    return 0
    else
    echo $1 is not integer
    return 1
    fi
}


if [[ $(isint $1) && $(isint $2) && $(isint $3) &&  $2 -lt $3  ]]; then
    if [[ $2 -le $1  &&  $1 -le $3 ]]; then
    echo "$1 is in the range [$2,$3]"
    else
    echo "$1 is not in the range [$2,$3]"
    fi
else
    echo usage: $0 INT1 INT2 INT3
fi
```

Here is my problem: the preceding script doesn't work, the

```
if [[ $(isint $1) && $(isint $2) && $(isint $3) &&  $2 -lt $3  ]]
```

never evaluates to true, if I want to obtain the wanted result I need to change the test to:

```
if [[ !$(isint $1) && !$(isint $2) && !$(isint $3) &&  $2 -lt $3  ]]
```

I don't get why this is working, the way I understood the `test`and `[[ ]]` commands is that they both evaluate the expressions passed to them, `0` evaluates to true and `1` evaluates to false. In my case if the correct parameters are passed to the script, the `isint` calls evaluate to 0, hence true, why the need for inverting them for the script to work as I want ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: hint: add `set -x` to the top of your script or add `-x` to the shebang on the first line: `#!/bin/bash -x`. That will let you see each line as it is evaluated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is the `$()` enclosing your calls to `isint`. These replace the command with the standard output of the call to `isint`, so in this case what you're really running is:

```
if [[ "$1 is integer" && "$2 is integer" && "$3 is integer" &&  $2 -lt $3  ]]
```

You want to use the return values instead, so just drop the `$()` and move the `isint`'s out of the brackets:

```
if isint "$1" && isint "$2" && isint "$3" &&  [[ "$2" -lt "$3"  ]]
```

I added some quotes as well: you really should have your arguments quoted throughout the whole thing.

Comment: The parens are a bad idea -- they cause a subshell to be spawned, which has a performance penalty. If you want grouping without explicit need for a subshell, use curly braces. However, I don't see any need for explicit grouping at all: `if` allows a compound command to start with.

Comment: (That said, I don't think that's worth a downvote -- the substance of this answer is correct. Might maybe make it `[[ "$1 is integer" && "$2 is integer" ...`, quoting your strings, to make things a bit clearer? -- but not my downvote).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point, that's true. The downvote was probably for v1 of this answer, where I had a pretty bad typo.

Comment: (Personally, btw, I'd use an arithmetic context, making it `(( $2 < $3 ))`).

Comment: Thank you, your solution is similar to that of @harvey, choosing yours as an answer for the extra explanations

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing up literal values with return codes. It should be this:

```
isint "$1" && isint "$2" && isint "$3" && [[ "$2" -lt "$3"  ]]
```

That says, run these four commands and see if they're all true (return code == 0).

Comment: Thank you, your solution works, but now you got me more confused, first of all you used the `&&` as a `AND_IF` command right ? second of all, I thought I needed a `test `command (or a similar command) after an `if`, does any command actually do the trick since any command has a return value?